# Google App Maker: How to assign id to HTML widget based on datasource?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a popup that is shown when a user clicks on the item of a list. Once the pop up shows, there is an HTML widget within it, in which I'd like to give it an 'id'  like:

```html
<div id="builder-<idOfItemSelectedHere>"></div>
```

How can I do this in Google app maker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would be a possible solution. For you listrow onclick event enter the following:

```
var htmlwidget = widget.root.descendants.YourHTMLWidget;
var item = widget.datasource.item;

htmlwidget.html = "<div id='builder-" + item.id + "'>" + item.id + "</div>";
```

You would want to remove your predefined html from your HTML widget however.